# Install extended applet on JavaCard

Tags: applet, javacard, globalplatform

How can I deploy an extended Java-Card-applet to my card?
Until now I've only dealt with classic applets and installed them with GlobalPlatformPro under OS X.

However, when I try to install an extended applet (using `gp -install KCIdentity.eap`) it fails with the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not figure out the package name of the applet!
at pro.javacard.gp.CapFile.<init>(CapFile.java:94)
at pro.javacard.gp.CapFile.<init>(CapFile.java:65)
at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:441)
```

Does anyone know how I can deploy my applet to my card (ideally using OS X, but Debian or Windows is also OK)?

Edit: Link to GlobalPlatformPro: https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro

Update:
This has nothing to do with extended APDUs but with the Java-VM-version. Classic applets use version 2.x whereas extended applets use version 3.y. NetBeans packages the extended applets in an *.eap-file which doesn't seem to be supported... However I'll look if I can package it in an *.cap-file. Renaming didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess with "extended applet" you are refering to an applet that Extended Length APDUs. To use extended length APDUs the `Applet` must implement the `ExtendedLength` interface fomr the standard javacard package. Otherwise the applet will return with `0x6700` to extended Length APDUs.

However, GP says that the package name could not be determined, so I suppose you did not properly convert/compile the CAP file. Therefore you should review your compilation process.

I suppose the `.eap` is a typo? Otherwise change that to `.cap`, which is the standard format for downloading applets to the card.

edit: answer in the comments.

edit: the reason turned out to be that the card does not support the connected edition. Javacard3 is divided into classic edition(basically an update on the Javacard 2.2.2 API) and the connected edition(new mechanisms like Webserver applets etc...).

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with extended APDUs but with the Java-VM-version. Classic applets use version 2.x whereas extended applets use version 3.y. NetBeans packages the extended applets in an *.eap-file which doesn't seem to be supported... However I'll look if I can package it in an *.cap-file. Renaming didn't work...

Comment: Still no clue what you are taking about. Do you mean classic vs connected edition? Jc3 classic is just the successor of jc2 with more API calls. If your card does not support the newest API  installation will of course fail

Comment: OK, I think I found our problem: I was referring to the same terminology used here; http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/javacard3-142122.html#3 and it seems, that the extended version is similar to the connected version which is not supported by my card...^^
So, only need to figure out how to create a JC3.y classic applet with NetBeans... You've pointed me to my problem, thank you 

Comment: I'd still expect to have reasonable errors, please file a issue on Github with the sample file (if possible) or at least trace